# Ubuntu laptop cant see shared printer on network

Tags: networking, printing

i have a network of 4 computers. 3 have windows installed and 1 with ubuntu 16.04.
The printer is installed and connected via usb to one of the windows pc, and shared via network. The 2 other pc with windows can see the printer with no problems. But the ubuntu one cant connect to the printer. I can see the printer in network and install it, but when im going to print it just says "cant connect to printer".
Any hints? Tried with different drivers, installed using different methods (network detect, ip, cups, etc), same result. Firewall is off btw. Printer is Hp p1102w

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is long out of date.

Comment: Update to a newer version of Ubuntu and your problem will likely be solved (and, if not, at least then we can help you far better).

Comment: My huge mistake, its 16.04 not 10.04 (fatfingers on phone, sorry)